# ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied, on Windows through Task Sheduler

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, permissions

I am trying to export all objects of specific oracle user by executing a batch file through Windows Task Sheduler:

```
exp.exe user/pass@dbname owner=user log=mylog.txt
```

The Oracle 11.2.0.4 x64 and the database are on that same Windows7 machine

The task starts OK. That is to mean that no wrong user or password issues are there. But when task is started by schedule, it says in the log:

> ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied

When task is started manually, under same user as the scheduled user (this user is member of `Administrators` group and `ora_dba` group, by the way), it works fine and export is done. The task is scheduled with an `Execute with highest privileges` checkbox in task properties, so I don't see why there is a difference between the "by schedule" and "manual" task start.

I've read a lot on `ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied` on this site, but all topics are concerning Linux. I tried to set permissions on c:\app\oracle, where my Oracle is installed. Actually, `Administrators` already by default had all permissions on that directory

I noticed that export of tables, however, works fine even in the task started by schedule:

```
exp.exe user/pass@dbname tables=mytable1,mytable2 log=mylog.txt
```

At any rate, the oracle user `user` has oracle rights to export entire database.

**Problem:**

Only-tables are exported fine, but with `owner=` export key I get `TNS:permission denied`, and only if Windows scheduled task is started by schedule, while manually started task does everything OK.

Comment: This is a dba related question, isn't it?(dba.stackexchange.com?)

Comment: Yes it apparently is dba-related. But basically same question, with the only difference being Linux instead of Windows, is answered here a number of times. Most answers were here, that's why I posted here

Comment: posted at dba.stackexchange.com too:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122081/ora-12546-tnspermission-denied-on-windows-through-task-scheduler